# Splitting dataset in SAS

Tags: split, sas, subset

I have a very large data set comprising of continuous & categorical variables & I need to split the same into continuous & categorical respectively.

Example of the data:

```
   AgeBand Name Price 

    20-30    A    200     
    30-40    B    300     
    40-50    C    400     
    50-60    D    100
```

I want to have 2 datasets:
1.Comrising ageband & name
2.Price
Can any one help out?

Comment: Can you add some example data? or more information about the variables? i.e are they all numeric, are the categorical variables all character etc

Comment: AgeBand 10-20,20-30,30-40,40-50,Amount paid -20,30,40,50,Type-A,B,C,D

Comment: Best to include the data in your question so it is reproducible. Also it isn't clear which variables you want seperated

Comment: Hi Andrew I have put a very small dummy. BUT THE REAL DATASET CONTAINS MORE THAN 100 VARIABLES.

Comment: How do you know which variables are continuous and which are categorical based in the name, which is all a program has to go on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `proc contents` to identify your types of variables. With this method you don't have to type the specific variables you want:

```
proc contents data = sashelp.class noprint out=names(keep=name type); run;

proc sql noprint;
    select name
    into: cont_vars separated by " "
    from names
    where type = 1;

    select name
    into: cat_vars separated by " "
    from names
    where type = 2;
quit;

%put &cont_vars.;
%put &cat_vars.;

data cont_vars(keep=&cont_vars.) cat_vars(keep=&cat_vars.); 
    set sashelp.class; 
run;
```

Comment: So what happens if there is a numeric categorical variable?  The only sure way to cope with this is detailed in the answer from @Joe

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to manage this is to have a data dictionary, which would be a file (maybe in excel or some other format, or native SAS) which stores the variable names and their types - whether they are categorical or continuous.

Then you can create variable lists from this data dictionary in order to split your variable.

Imagining you have a excel file `"c:\mydata\data_dictionary.xlsx"`, then:

```
proc import file="c:\mydata\data_dictionary.xlsx"
            out=datadict dbms=xlsx replace;  *or dbms=excel or excelcs depending on your installation and version;
  sheet="datadict_sheet";
run;


proc sql;
  select colname 
    into :cat_var_list separated by ' '
    from datadict
    where coltype = 'Categorical'
  ;
  select colname 
    into :cont_var_list separated by ' '
    from datadict
    where coltype = 'Continuous'
  ;
quit;

data cat_vars(keep=&cat_var_list. idvar) cont_vars(keep=&cont_var_list. idvar);
  set yourdata;
run;
```

You need to make sure you keep your ID variable (whatever that is) in both datasets of course.